# ReadExternalStorage permission is rejected, even after declaring it in the manifest

Tags: java, android

I know this is a really basic question but I'm stuck. I've declared that my app uses the read external storage permission, but my app is crashing when I try to perform an action that requires the permission.  Here is the manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera"
                  android:required="false" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: Permissions and features should be listed outside of the `<application>` tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the declarations to be children of the manifest, not the application:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest ... >
  <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera"
              android:required="false" />

  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

  <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

  <activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```